# Functions unavailable in DiffSharp

Tags: pytorch, f#, tensor, libtorch, diffsharp

I have successfully installed DiffSharp (along with TorchSharp, Libsharp etc.), using the following F# script:

```
#r "nuget: DiffSharp.Core"
#r "nuget: DiffSharp.Backends.Reference"
#r "nuget: DiffSharp.Data"
#r "nuget: DiffSharp.Backends.Torch"
#r "nuget: TorchSharp"
#r "nuget: LibTorchSharp"

open System
open DiffSharp
open DiffSharp.Data
open DiffSharp.Model
open DiffSharp.Compose
open DiffSharp.Util
open DiffSharp.Optim
```

The following functions however, are not available (which should be, according to the DiffSharp API reference):

```
dsharp.config(backend=Backend.Torch, device=Device.CPU)
dsharp.seed(1)
let x = dsharp.randn([1024; 5])
```

Any ideas why? Am I missing any library or open statement?

Comment: How do you know that they're unavailable?

Comment: Specific error message is: "System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Tensor TorchSharp.torch.randn(Int64[], System.Nullable`1<ScalarType>, Device, Boolean, Generator)'."

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Because the error message says methods are not to be found...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why this is not working, but the [DiffSharp installation isntructions](https://diffsharp.github.io/install.html) recommend using the `DiffSharp-cpu` package (or one for `cuda` or `lite` version if you have LibTorch already) and that works fine for me:

```
#r "nuget: DiffSharp-cpu"

open DiffSharp

dsharp.config(backend=Backend.Torch, device=Device.CPU)
dsharp.seed(1)
let x = dsharp.randn([1024; 5])
```

Produces:

```
val x: Tensor =
  tensor([[-1.5256, -0.7502, -0.6540, -1.6095, -0.1002], ...])
```

Comment: This actually did work, many thanks. Now, if I want to load the corresponding libraries (DLLs) directly from my HDD, any idea which ones to load (to speed things up)? Just loading DiffSharp-cpu.dll was not sufficient, and loading those I indicated earlier also causes the original problem again.